# Pass form parameters with parameter name and replace "&" with "/"

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in html and i am passing the fields into a URL into a booking agent accubook. It originally worked until the changed how they are taking in the the values.

I thought the function would use "/" instead of "&" the js file works with the calendar displays so im not sure what i am doing wrong?

HTML FORM:

```
<form id="form1" role="form" action="https://example.com/111" class="" method="post"> 

(form here)

<button class="btn btn-warning btn-md floatright">Book</a>
```

.js file:

```
function Querystring(qs) { // optionally pass a querystring to parse
    this.params = {};

    if (qs == null) qs = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);
    if (qs.length == 0) return;

    // Turn <plus> back to <space>
    // See: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1
    qs = qs.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
    var args = qs.split('/'); // parse out name/value pairs separated via &

    // split out each name=value pair
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        var pair = args[i].split('');
        var name = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);

        var value = (pair.length == 2)
            ? decodeURIComponent(pair[1])
            : name;

        this.params[name] = value;
    }
}
```

I am passing in https://example.html?arrival=2019-08-10&departure=2019-08-13

I need https://example.html/2019-08-10/2019-08-13

Comment: `url=url.replace(/[?&][^=]+=/g,'/')` where `url` is the URL you want to modify. But I kind of question this functionality.. you're stripping away the keys so how do you know which one is `arrival` vs. `departure` if the query params get swapped in URL?

Comment: I need to strip away the keys in the URL as this is how the booking agent wants the values passed in. I have no control over the booking agent, the originally had it with the keys and now they want it passed in with no keys

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most robust solution, and it makes assumptions like that you won't have like malformed query parameters, but this may help you:

```
function QueryString(qs) {
    const [url, queryParams] = qs.split('?')
    return url + '/' + queryParams.split('&').map( param => param.split('=')[1]).join('/')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `URLSearchParams` object has been introduced to handle parsing and retrieving query string arguments. This way all the ugly parts of parsing urls is abstracted. Fair warning, this is not yet supported in Internet Explorer.

```js
function Querystring(qs) {
 var inputUrl = qs || window.location.search;
 var domainPart = inputUrl.substring(0, inputUrl.indexOf('?'));
 var searchPart = inputUrl.substring(inputUrl.indexOf('?'));

    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(searchPart);
    var keys = urlParams.keys();
    var url = domainPart;
    
    for(let key of keys) { 
      url += '/' + urlParams.get(key);
    }
    
    return url;
}

console.log(Querystring('https://example.com?arrival=2019-08-10&departure=2019-08-13'));
```

Checkout the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams